# how long property is alive

Tags: c#

I have simple C# thread with lots of properties. How long property is alive becouse in properties i store some data.

Can be property alive more than 1 months and store data or is better to use DB.

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, a variable is kept alive as long as it has at least one active reference. In your case, as long as the object containing your property remains "in scope", the value of your property is kept in memory. For a static variable, or one created in the main() function or belonging to an Application or Service base object, it will stay in memory as long as the program runs.

However, a month is a very long time to expect a thread to run. If the thread encounters an error it can't handle, it will terminate, and you lose everything that the thread hadn't persisted to the file system or a database. In addition, web applications are maintained in an "app pool", and even within the context of a user session, the app pool can be "recycled", and everything that was just hanging around in memory is lost. So, if this data is important to keep around after the thread has run, or between threads, save it somewhere as your thread goes along its business.

Answer (score 3):

As long as your program can stay running for more than a month the data will be there.  It sounds like you should really use a database though.  What happens if you lose power or you need to restart the server for maintenance?

Answer (score 3):

Your properties will remain alive as long as your app remains alive.  One month is a long time for an app to sit there - I'd recommend using a DB, if you want to ensure that you don't ever lose data.

Answer (score 2):

They're alive until they're garbage collected -- so if you leave your application running for the next hundred years, and the properties remain within the scope of your applications usage, the values will persist indefinitely.  However, if you're planning on long term storage, a database would probably be a smarter idea, as your values will be removed, for instance, if the object persisting the values is removed/deconstructed, application is stopped, errors out, or computer reset, etc.

Keep in mind, a database can be anything that persists your values, whether it's a flat file, hierarchical, or relational database.

Answer (score 1):

A thread is a path of execution, not an object.  Objects have properties that can store data.  Objects (and their properties) don't really live *in* a thread, though a thread can act on them.  Threads can come and go in the course of an application's execution.  Objects get deleted by the garbage collector after they are no longer being referred to.  Code like this...

```
Object o = new Object();
```

... does two things 1) create an object, 2) create a reference to that object (o).  If you set `o = null;`, you've removed the only reference to that object and the garbage collector will clean it up soon.  None of the threads or objects in your application will live longer than the application itself; they will all be wiped away when your program ends its execution and the process space is destroyed.  Any data that needs to outlive the process should be stored to a file or a database table, etc.  Data can easily outlive a thread by being in an object that is referenced outside the function that the thread executes, but it won't outlive the process.